# Regular expression exec return null or normal value

Tags: javascript, regex

The regular expression alternates between returning a normal value and null. I tried to google, well, I couldn't find anything.

```js
const functionCall = /(?<name>\w+)\((?<s>\))?/g;
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const func = functionCall.exec("s(1, 2)");
    console.log(func)
}
```

In console

```
Array(3) [...]
null
Array(3) [...]
null
...
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How to fix this

Comment: Get rid of the `g` flag.

Comment: @Pointy is correct

Answer (score 1):

Global regular expressions have their `lastIndex` property updated when `exec` is called. The next time `exec` is called, it will only search starting from that `lastIndex`.

In your example, the first iteration will find a match and advance the `lastIndex`. The next iteration will not find a match starting from that index, so the `lastIndex` gets reset to `0`. This repeats every 2 iterations.

Removing the `g` flag will make the regular expression no longer stateful.

```js
const functionCall = /(?<name>\w+)\((?<s>\))?/;
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const func = functionCall.exec("s(1, 2)");
    console.log(func)
}
```